# Проблема с $_GET

Tags: php

Здравствуйте помогите решить проблему выдает такая ошибка при запуске страницы:

```
Undefined index: id_topic in C:\wamp64\www\forum1\view_topic.php on line 42
```

Хотя данное название есть в таблице и я хочу взять его id и отображать его значение по данному id. Вот этот код расположенной по 42 линии:

```
$id = $_GET['id_topic'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id_topic='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
if ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    //значения из таблицы через $rows
}
```

Использую php7 и помогите с этим разобраться. Таблица Mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_question` (
  `id_topic` int(31) NOT NULL,
  `topic` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `detail` longtext NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `view` int(31) NOT NULL,
  `reply` int(31) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Покажите листинг view_topic.php, если он не очень большой)

Comment: $id = $_GET['id_topic']; Вот здесь у вас ошибка,в массиве нет значения с таким индексом.Возможно не правильно передаете параметры в GET,проверьте

Comment: Покажите форму или что у вас там запускает этот get? Или скопируйте и приведите тут из адресной строки

Comment: Сам файл https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzuVepyc1IA5clNManlpdUF0MkE

Comment: @ЕлдосКадыркул Так. Покажите мне что у вас в адресной строке, когда вы заходите на эту страницу и появляется эта ошибка. Просто скопируйте весь адрес и пришлите сюда

Comment: quaresma89 прав, в вашем листинге нет проверки на метод запроса. Вы присваиваете переменную ГЕТ при каждой загрузке файла, не зависимо от того, как вы пришли на этот урл и принесли ли массив ГЕТ.

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: Покажи как ты формируешь ссылку, для перехода к этому id_topic, какой у тебя адрес находится в строке браузера когда ты переходишь на эту страницу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема не в том, есть ли у вас такая строчка в базе данных, а в том, что вы не передаете номер строки в URL страницы.

Если вы хотите получить здесь id

```
$id = $_GET['id_topic'];
```

То адрес страницы должен быть:

http://yoursite.ru/path/toscript.php**?id_topic=42**

Тогда

```
$id = $_GET['id_topic']; //id теперь 42.
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно по Вашему вопросу необходимо проверить установку в переменную $_GET['id_topic'] какого либо значения

т.е.

```
if (isset($_GET['id_topic'])) 
{ 
$id = $_GET['id_topic'];

....

<?php } ?>
```

Но на самом деле это полумера просто убирающая ошибку

Еще необходимо сделать еще обработчик ошибок в случае если не задан $_GET['id_topic'] (например выводить "Тема с таким ID не найдена"), и id_topic может не существует в БД.

Еще желательно также протестировать весь скрипт на наличие ссылок без такого GET параметра, т.е. все ссылки ведущие на данную страницу должны в адресной строке содержать id_topic=(число)